# Can you set spark settings in Hive on Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, orc

There's a setting I use for ORC in Spark, for proper schema evolution:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.impl", "native")
```

The other one that exists besides `native` is `hive`. But its schema evolution capabilities suck.

So, I was wondering, since I am using Hive on Spark, can I somehow set `spark.sql.orc.impl` from in Hive?